# Facebook Messenger Web hooks Only Delivering for My Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I created a facebook "bot" which has pages_messaging permissions granted, I can run the following subscribe code successfully:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -d "access_token=PageTokenOfAnotherPage" \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/PageIDOfOtherPage/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=feed,mention,name,picture,category,description,conversations,branded_camera,feature_access_list,standby,messages,messaging_account_linking,messaging_checkout_updates,message_echoes,message_deliveries,messaging_game_plays,messaging_optins,messaging_optouts,messaging_payments,messaging_postbacks,messaging_pre_checkouts,message_reads,messaging_referrals,messaging_handovers,messaging_policy_enforcement,messaging_page_feedback,messaging_appointments,founded,company_overview,mission,products,general_info,leadgen,leadgen_fat,location,hours,parking,public_transit,page_about_story,phone,email,website,ratings,attire,payment_options,culinary_team,general_manager,price_range,awards,hometown,current_location,bio,affiliation,birthday,personal_info,personal_interests,publisher_subscriptions,members,checkins,page_upcoming_change,page_change_proposal,merchant_review,product_review,videos,live_videos,registration"
```

And I get back a 200 OK here with {"success":true} and when something other than a message happens, post, like, etc I get that back on my web hook, but not messages, what in the world am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: _“which has pages_messaging permissions granted”_ - so the admin of that other page explicitly granted that permission to your app, yes? You are not just talking about Facebook approving this permission in app review, right?

Comment: Correct, the admin has granted me access, I can run a <their_page_id>/subscribed_apps has registered with my app with:

"messages",
        "messaging_account_linking",
        "messaging_checkout_updates",
        "message_echoes",
       ....... a bunch of other items too long to list :-)

And I get web hooks on things like likes or posts, etc just fine, it's just the messages that aren't being web hooked. Inside Facebook my app has the permissions pages_messaging and manage_pages.

Comment: I am not sure if you might not need `read_page_mailboxes` as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this one, was I forgot to add the **pages_messaging** in the oauth scope for the **user token**. Super important when you get the pages_messaging approved by Facebook be sure to go add it back into the scope.

Hope this helps someone else!